# Angular: station placement css

Tags: css, angular

I fetched this data from the server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkuad.png)

I want to design them to be located according to the following image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwcZp.png)

I don't know how to reference all the stations in a generic way

In the html I have the following

```
<span *ngFor="let all of stations; let i = index">
<span class="station">{{all.staionName}}</span>
</span>
```

I manage to do it in a non-generic way but it's not what I want:

```
<div *ngIf="stations?.length">
    {{stations[0].staionName}}
    {{stations[1].staionName}}
    {{stations[2].staionName}}
    {{stations[3].staionName}}
    {{stations[4].staionName}}
    {{stations[5].staionName}}
    {{stations[6].staionName}}
    {{stations[7].staionName}}
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if that "let i = index" is correctly written. Let's try "index as i".

Comment: It's the same not good for me either